# Using javascript scoped variable inside rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In some javascript function i am passing a variable. Now i want to use this variable inside the rails helper method

The code snippet looks like:

```
function changeDate(cell,id)
{
    cell.innerHTML =  '<%= text_field_tag "start_date#{id}","{@now.to_date}", :size => 10, :class => nil  %><%= escape_javascript(calendar_for("start_date#{id}"))%>';
}
```

Above is the Wrong Way of doing the same.

One way to do this could be, I use the html generated by the helper method directly in js function instead of the rails helper

like this

```
function changeDate(cell,id)
{
    cell.innerHTML =  '<input class="date noborder" id="start_date' + id + '" name="start_date" size="10" type="text" value="2012-04-05" />...';
}
```

so i can easily use javascript variable inside my function.

But i am looking for a better approach.

***What will be the rails way of using javascript variable inside rails helper?***

Any directions/suggestions would be great and helpful.

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a javascript expert, but I'm gonna say that according to my experience, no. I think the fundamental problem is that your javascript and your erb are running in different places. The erb is run server side, which means that the javascript, which runs client side, hasn't even started executing yet. Thus, there's no way for your erb to know what the value of a given js variable is going to be while the erb is running.

Comment: even i thought so. lets see if theres a work around. thnx for your reply though.